# Ist die Benutzung des Wörtchens "wo" in Zusammenhang mit Zeitangaben korrekt?

Tags: grammaticality

Hier ist ein Zitat aus dem Buch *Die Stadt der Träumenden Bücher* von Walter Moers:

> *Es gibt Momente beim Schreiben, **wo** die Dinge in Fluß geraten und im Fluß bleiben müssen, und das geht nur, wenn man den richtigen Arm benutzt.*

Ist dies grammatikalisch korrekt? Sollte es nicht

> *Es gibt Momente beim Schreiben, **in denen**...*

heißen?

Comment: Es ist ein ewiges hin und her. Der eine meint so, der andere so. Und was ist nun richtig? Beispiel: das ist der Moment, "in dem" oder "wo" das Eis der Augen taut.

Comment: Oder "Es gibt Momente beim Schreiben, wenn die Dinge" oder "Das ist der Moment, da". Bestimmt in Kürze auch in Ihrer Hörweite: "Das ist der Moment, in dem wo ..."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Der Satz ist m.E. korrekt. „Wo“ kann auch einen Relativsatz zur Temporalbestimmung einleiten: Beispiele bei [canoo](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Komplex/Funktion/Attribut/Relativ/Einleitung.html#Anchor-temporal) und [im Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wo_Fragewort_Relativpronomen#Bedeutung2b).

EDIT:

Die Formulierung ist seit Langem Bestandteil der höheren Standardsprache und findet sich sowohl in überregionalen Tageszeitungen als auch bei anspruchsvollen Schriftstellern:

- [Frank Schirrmacher, FAZ, Feuilleton, 18.03.2011](https://www.faz.net/frankfurter-allgemeine-zeitung/feuilleton/der-moment-in-dem-man-versteht-1611350.html): „*Es sind die Momente, wo es jemandem gelingt, ein gerade ablaufendes Ereignis zu historisieren.*“

(Mehr Treffer etwa von faz.net, sueddeutsche.de oder zeit.de kann sich jeder selber ergoogeln).

- Robert Musil, Die Verwirrungen des Zöglings Törleß: „*Man muß das Gefühl seines Lebens als eines ruhig Gleitenden in sich erwecken. In dem Momente, wo dies gelingt, ist man dem Tode ebenso nah als dem Leben.*“
- Theodor Fontane, Schach von Wuthenow: „*Ein gewisser Reiz der Erscheinung ist ihr freilich geblieben, aber es sind immer nur Momente, wo die seltene Liebenswürdigkeit ihrer Natur einen Schönheitsschleier über sie wirft, und den Zauber ihrer früheren Tage wiederherzustellen scheint.*“
- Gottfried Keller, Die Leute von Seldwyla: „*Es waren nur wenige Momente, wo sie etwas Entscheidendes und Energisches gegen seine junge Selbstaendigkeit unternahm, aber jedesmal zur rechten Zeit und so ploetzlich, einleuchtend und
  bedeutsam, dass es nie seiner bleibenden Wirkung ermangelte.*“
- Christoph Martin Wieland, Oberon: „*Als eine, die kaum ihren Augen glaubt, | Steht Rezia, des Athems fast beraubt. | Welch Wunder! ruft sie aus; und just in dem Momente, | Wo nichts als dieß uns beide retten könnte!*“
- Friedrich Wilhelm Nietzsche, Menschliches, Allzumenschliches: „*Die Religionsstifter unterscheiden sich dadurch von jenen großen Betrügern, dass sie aus diesem Zustande der Selbsttäuschung nicht herauskommen: oder sie haben ganz selten einmal jene helleren Momente, wo der Zweifel sie überwältigt; gewöhnlich trösten sie sich aber, diese helleren Momente dem bösen Widersacher
  zuschiebend.*“
- Robert Walser, Aufsätze („Guten Abend, Jungfer“): „*Er bewundert sie ohnegleichen in dem Moment, wo sie sich seinen entsetzlichen Plänen überliefert.*“
- Max Brod, Über die Schönheit häßlicher Bilder: „*Und dann, in dem Moment, wo er glaubt, diese Frau liebe ihn doch, schmeißt er seine Bücher weg, verschmäht eine Freundschaft, tanzt und bestellt Champagner (genau Champagner!).*“
- Victor Hehn, Über Goethes Hermann und Dorothea: „*Diese Worte malen aufs glücklichste den Zustand des Himmels und der Erde in dem Moment, wo Gewitterwolken die Sonne zu verhüllen drohen.*“
- Johann Wolfgang von Goethe, Faust: Der Tragödie zweiter Teil: „*Ehrt den Moment, wo manche Tausend schreiten, | Für oder wider mich zu streiten.*“
- Alexander von Humboldt, Reise in die Aequinoctial-Gegenden des
  neuen Continents. Band 3: „*Letztere Annahme scheint mir die wahrscheinlichere; denn hält man dem Culex cyanopterus ruhig den Handrücken hin, so ist der Schmerz anfangs sehr heftig, nimmt aber immer mehr ab, je mehr das Insekt
  fortsaugt, und hört ganz auf im Moment, wo es von selbst fortfliegt.*“
- Theodor Mommsen, Römische Geschichte, Buch 3: „*Die Schlacht bei Pydna bezeichnet aber auch zugleich den letzten Moment, wo der Senat noch festhält an der Staatsmaxime, wo irgend möglich jenseits der italischen Meere keine Besitzungen und keine Besatzungen zu uebernehmen, sondern jene zahllosen Klientelstaaten durch die bloße politische Suprematie in Ordnung 
  zu halten.*“
- Johann Gustav Droysen, Geschichte Alexanders des Grossen: „*Ob der Zug des Epiroten Alexandros nach Italien im Einverständnis mit dem makedonischen Könige oder in Rivalität gegen denselben unternommen sein mochte, es gab einen Moment, wo er mit seinen Siegen das Griechentum Italiens sich stolzer denn je erheben zu sollen schien.*“

Comment: +1 In der Tat. Laut Duden scheint sogar *das ist der Mann, wo am Steuer gesessen hat* korrekt zu sein. Was ist dann noch falsch?

Comment: Das ist explizit als „`landschaftlich salopp, nicht standardsprachlich`“ gekennzeichnet, und es ist kein Beispiel für eine Temporalbestimmung. Daher läßt sich das nicht mit Deinem Beispiel vergleichen. Der Bezug des „wo“ in Deinem Beispiel ist „Momente“ - der zeitliche Bezug ist daher offensichtlich. Es geht also nur um die konkrete Frage, ob eine Temporalbestimmung mit „wo“ standardsprachlich zulässig ist.

Comment: Der Duden ist auch nur ein Buch (schon die amtliche Rechtschreibung gibt er nicht korrekt wieder). Mir stößt "Momente, wo" in einem literarischen Text sehr auf. Ich denke, dass der Duden hier eine alltagssprachliche Sprechpraxis als Standard verzeichnet (also deskriptiv ist, nicht normativ). Moers' Sprache ist nicht literarisch, sondern ein Mischmasch aus literatursprachlichen Versatzstücken, gesprochener Alltagssprache und Idiosynkrasien. Meiner Meinung nach würde man "Momente, wo" niemals in einer überregionalen Tageszeitung oder bei einem anspruchsvollen Schriftsteller lesen.

Comment: Deine Meinung, lieber @what, in allen Ehren - hier liegst Du offensichtlich falsch. Ich habe meine Antwort um ein paar - Deiner Meinung nach sicherlich nicht anspruchsvoller - Schriftsteller und Werkauszüge ergänzt. Wenn man mehr Zeit hätte, könnte man noch viel weiteres zu Tage fördern - aber ich denke, die Auswahl reicht, um die Dinge richtig zu stellen.

Comment: Du magst Recht haben, tohuwawohu, und "Moment, wo ist wirklich korrekt. Aber deine Beispiele sind alle veraltet. Schon mal was von Sprachwandel gehört? Niemand heute redet und schreibt wie Goethe. Finde mal Zitate aus der Gegenwart, dann bin ich überzeugt.

Comment: Was darfs denn noch sein? Ich habe bereits darauf hingewiesen, dass sich mittels der gebräuchlichen Suchmaschinen auch aus den von Dir angemahnten "überregionalen" Tageszeitungen hunderte Nachweise finden lassen - das gilt auch für literarische Äußerungen von zB Peter Handtke. Mach' Dir die Arbeit bitteschön selber. Übrigens: Zu den Zitaten aus der Gegenwart zählt auch die in der Frage zitierte Passage von W. Moers. Wir haben also Wörterbücher, Zeitschriften, klassische und moderne Autoren, aber @what genügt das immer noch nicht. Sorry - aber das ist nicht mehr mein Problem.

Comment: PS: Interessant finde ich die Ansicht, Schirrmacher sei kein Autor der Gegenwart (böse Zungen sagen, dass daran tatsächlich etwas dran sei...).

Comment: Auch wenn schon sieben Jahre seit dieser Antwort verstrichen sind, möchte ich noch auf das folgende Video von Belles Lettres aufmerksam machen: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cjVOwiKDENo.

Answer (score 1):

Klasse Frage - für mich als Schwabe ebenfalls interessant! :-)

In tohuwawohus Antwort plus Kommentaren wird ja schon eifrig über die offizielle Korrektheit diskutiert. Ich will eine persönliche Meinung/Erfahrung hinzufügen (.

Die für ihr ausgezeichnetes Hochdeutsch bekannten Schwaben (Achtung, Ironie!) benutzen dieses Wörtchen äußerst gerne. Ich bin allerdings der Meinung, dass dessen Gebrauch außerhalb der Ort- oder Zeitbestimmung nicht korrekt ist. So wurde es mir bisher beigebracht (alte, wie auch neue Rechtschreibung). Wie die Bespiele in tohuwawohus Antwort zeigen, ist der Gebrauch von "wo" dennoch vielfältig, was allerdings noch lang nicht die Korrektheit beweist.

Deswegen mein persönlicher Ratschlag an jene, die Deutsch als Fremdsprache lernen: Versucht den Gebrauch von wo außerhalb der Zeit- und Ortbestimmung zu vermeiden.

Comment: Kurze Frage - vielleicht verstehe ich es ja einfach nicht: Wann wäre bitte genau "die Korrektheit bewiesen"?

Comment: Sorry, noch ein Nachtrag: Ich nehme nicht für mich in Anspruch, "die Korrektheit bewiesen" zu haben. Aber die Indizien dafür, dass man mit dieser Formulierung nichts falsch macht, halte ich bei der Quellenlage für überwältigend. Im Gegensatz dazu hat leider noch niemand einen Beleg (keinen **Beweis**, ein **Beleg** würde ja schon ausreichen) für das Gegenteil geliefert - oder anders gesagt: wird die Temporalbestimmung mit "wo" irgendwo explizit als (grammatisch oder stilistisch) falsch bezeichnet?

Comment: Ich versteh die ganze Diskussion um dieses kleine Wörtchen nicht, wo ich doch dennoch beiden Seiten recht gebe. Es gibt oft Momente, wo ein 'formelles' *in denen* oder Äquivalentes besser ist, wo ich mir aber nicht immer sicher bin. In jedem Fall kann man nahezu fast überall ein *wo* einsetzen, wo einem es gefällt, wo es aber nich unbedingt die beste Lösung ist. Aber warum einem Fremdsprachler anraten, das Wort zu meiden, wo es doch so schön kurz ist. Außerdem erspart man sich Fragen wie: Ist es *Momente, in denen* (Google 2 mio hits) oder *Momente, bei denen* (immerhin 200k hits).

Comment: Vorneweg, in meiner Antwort beziehe ich mich auf die allgemeine Nutzung von "wo" und will damit Sätze wie "die, wo ..." verhindern. Dem Fragetitel ist nicht direkt zu entnehmen, dass es sich hier um den speziellen Fall der "wo-Nutzung" im temporalen Sinn handelt. Die Benutzung von wo scheint in diesem Fall in der Tat gebräuchlich, jedoch "fühlt" sich diese für mich weiterhin falsch/umgangssprachlich an. Wie tohuwawohu korrekt anmerkt, sollte ich dafür allerdings auch einen Beleg anführen. Ich mache mich auf die Suche!

Comment: Wie soll man bitte einen Beleg für die Falschheit einer gebräuchlichen sprachlichen Wendung erbringen? Falsches Deutsch existiert, ihre Falschheit kann niemals bewiesen sondern bestenfalls behauptet werden. Das habe ich oben. Wo ist örtlich, nicht zeitlich. Wer es anders verwendet, ist von dialektalem Gebrauch beeinflusst (wie übrigens auch Goethe, der ja geradezu berühmt dafür ist, nicht standardsprachlich zu schreiben).

Comment: @what: Behauten kann man viel. Ich kann auch behaupten, dass man "Fisch" mit zwei "s" schreiben müsse. Was die Behauptung nicht richtiger macht. Wie man einen Beleg für die Falschheit einer sprachlichen Wendung erbringt? Nun, ganz einfach: Indem man ein Werk zitiert, das die Falschheit behauptet, und bei dessen Autor(en) man aufgrund objektiver Fakten von einer hinreichenden Sachkenntnis ausgehen kann, um eine solche Aussage zu treffen.

Answer (score 0):

*wo* entspricht lautlich viel eher dem ursprünglich indogermanischen Relativpronomen *k^wo, daher auch bspw. En *who*.

En *where*, AHD *wor*, "wo" werden mit einem zusätzlichen Partikel *-r* gebildet. Weshalb man annehmen sollte, dieser sei nun wieder verloren gegangen, weiß ich nicht, und meine Vermutung eines Zusammenhangs mit *woher* und *wer* ("woher weißt du das" ~ "von wem") konnte ich noch nicht überprüfen. Man könnte ebensogut annehmen, *wo* wäre in Dialekt durchgängig erhalten geblieben und die hier fragliche Wendung mit zeitlichem Aspekt könnte wohl dafürsprechen.

Comment: Jenes Partikel *r* ist umso interessanter, da die Partikel auch bindend bzw vorangestellt verwendet wurden (so ist die Wurzel von *ge-* in Griechisch und Sanskrit als Suffix reflektiert). So wäre *worum* nicht etwa *woherum* ein möglicher Hinnweis, dass *rum, rauf, runter* nicht nur reine Ellipsen von *herum* etc. sind. Die Frage kam vor kurzem auf, sicher genug für eine Antwort dort bin ich aber nicht.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25975)

Comment: @sgf it is not a definite answer, sure, which is the norm for descriptive answers. This answer provides diachronic justification for using *wo* anyway. As such it is an answer.  It is not well proven and requires a little bit of work to understand. It is built on the synchronic explanation in the other answers, especially the comparison to French. So much should be understood. The errosion of grammatic morphemes  in German has a long history. Arguing preferences in favour or against it would be an opinion, not an answer.

Comment: In other words, OP is asking, "hab ich mich da gerade verhört?" And I answer "No, not at all." and I hope I will find a reference to back it up eventually. I'll see to the secondary question about "in dem".